# PHP Array sort without using pre-defined sort functions?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have my_array = array(43,12,1,67,8);

I want to sort it **without** using any php sort functions.

Comment: Read about [Gnome Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort). But the counter question is 'Why'?

Comment: why not build a fresh new sorting algo first and then implement it in php ?? ...any nightmare for reinventing the wheel ??

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like a homework question... are you supposed to use any particular sort algorithm?

Answer (score 10):

```
Try This..!!

<?php
$array = array(43,12,1,67,8);

for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
 $value = MAX($array); 
 $key = array_search($value, $array); 

  if (($key = array_search($value, $array)) !== false) {
        unset($array[$key]);
   }
$sorted[]=$value;
}
print_r($sorted);


?>
```

Comment: @DaveChen The question is about avoiding sort functions, so that's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: it prints `Array ( [0] => 67 [1] => 43 [2] => 12 `, we have  replace the above code  `for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){` to `$array_total=count($array); for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){` now it gets output as `Array ( [0] => 67 [1] => 43 [2] => 12[3] => 8 [4] => 1  ` because i will be increase in loop

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own sorting function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm